# File data changed after encrypting then decrypting

Tags: c#

I encrypted a file using DES then After decrypting it successfully at the server and using

```
System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(@"c:\test\" + fileName, decryptedFile);
```

method the file data changed a little it the text is "Encrypting and Decrypting usind DES blah blah blah blah"
the text in the end file after decrypting is " k$nlng and Decrypting usind DES blah blah blah blah"
and i also tried this:

```
using (BinaryWriter binWriter =
                        new BinaryWriter(File.Open(@"C:\Test\" + fileName, FileMode.Create)))
                {
                    binWriter.Write(decryptedFile);
                }
```

the text still not the same
encrypting by :

```
public byte [] DESEncrypt(byte [] fileBytes)
    {
        CryptoStreamMode mode = CryptoStreamMode.Write;

        // Set up streams and encrypt
        MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream();
        CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memStream, 
            cryptoProvider.CreateEncryptor(cryptoProvider.Key, cryptoProvider.Key), mode);
        cryptoStream.Write(fileBytes, 0, fileBytes.Length);
        cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();

        // Read the encrypted message from the memory stream
        byte[] encryptedMessageBytes = new byte[memStream.Length];
        memStream.Position = 0;
        memStream.Read(encryptedMessageBytes, 0, encryptedMessageBytes.Length);
        MessageBox.Show("encrypted DES");
        return encryptedMessageBytes;
    }
```

decrypting by:

```
static public byte[] DESdecrypt(byte [] fileBytes)
    {

        ICryptoTransform decryptor = cryptoProvider.CreateDecryptor();
        byte[] originalAgain = decryptor.TransformFinalBlock(fileBytes, 0, fileBytes.Length);

        return originalAgain;
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: If you would post the code that you are using to encrypt and decrypt,  it would be helpful...

Comment: How exactly are you encrypting and decrypting it? You haven't given us nearly enough information to figure out what you're doing wrong.

Comment: codes added i thought it was saving problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing the same value for your "key" and "iv" value.  Each time you call the function, your "iv" value gets updated (thus, your key gets changed).

So you basically are doing this:

key = "key"
Encrypt (key, key)

-- key has now changed.

What you need to do is:

key = "key"
iv = copy of key
Encrypt (key, iv)

Comment: Thanks problem solved when i changed the decrypting code and passed the key and IV "copy of the key" to it. its unsafe to use the key as IV but its a start :D

Answer (score 0):

hard to say,  not an expert on the subject but compare your bytes before encrypting and after encrypting and decrypting. If they are identical no issues with the process. WriteALLBytes might not be the only thing.  think MIME type . a similar issue is i had to specifically say what type of file i am saving.